# Using matplotlib to represent three variables in two dimensions with colors

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

So I have two arrays, one representing my x values and one representing my y values. Lets call them

x = [2, 40, 5, 900]

y = [4, 8, 90, 20]

each of these arrays has a third quntity associated with them indicating the brightness at that point, lets call it

z = [10, 9 , 15, 14]

I want to plot the x and y points on a two dimensional axis and represent these z values as changes in color (darker colors for larger numbers). Any ideas? I am fairly stumped.